# Retrieve the [StructLayout] attribute of a struct

Tags: c#, struct, sizeof

I would like to fetch the struct size of 22 bytes from the StructLayout applied to the following structure.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1, Size = 22)]
internal unsafe struct Entry
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private fixed char title[14];
    [FieldOffset(14)]
    private readonly int size;
    [FieldOffset(18)]
    private readonly int start;
}
```

One would advise Marshal.SizeOf but it returns the size of the unmanaged object of 28 bytes which is undesired.

```
int count = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Entry));
```

However, getting this attribute seems not possible as the array 'customAttributes' is always of length 0.

```
var type = typeof(Entry);
var customAttributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StructLayoutAttribute), true);
```

Any workaround ?

Comment: SLA is special, it is already built into the Type class.  Use the type.StructLayoutAttribute property in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information in the StructLayout attribute is embedded in the method as IL directives, not as a custom property. To retrieve it, you can use the [Type.StructLayoutAttribute Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.structlayoutattribute.aspx):

```
var type = typeof(Entry);
var sla = type.StructLayoutAttribute;
```

Alternatively, if the struct is under your control you could simply define a Size constant:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = Entry.Size)]
internal unsafe struct Entry
{
    public const int Size = 22;
    ...
```